# CRAN/ Bioconductor package installs fail: Error: Line starting '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLI ...' is malformed

Tags: r, redirect, installation, package, cran

I have just made a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 installation and installed R following the instructions at [this link](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476713/how-to-upgrade-r-in-ubuntu), selecting the Berkeley mirror as I always do.

On emacs (+ess), I am unable to install any CRAN or Bioconductor package at all, for example:

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
```

Or:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("biomaRt")
```

I constantly get the following error:

```
Error: Line starting '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLI ...' is malformed!
```

Following on [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836371/r-bioconductor-installation-error-line-starting-doctype-html-publi-is), I have just waited to see if the problem solved by itself, but after 2 days I keep getting the same error. Any suggestion??

Comment: This is a generic issue with any package when trying to download from an URL that is a redirect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright I already solved the problem, turns out when prompting to select a CRAN mirror, I was selecting

```
USA (CA1) [https]
```

Instead of

```
(HTTP mirrors)
```

This is a feature I had never seen...

[image]

Selecting HTTP mirrors brings me to the list of mirrors I was expecting, and selecting now

```
USA (CA1)
```

Makes the installation process work perfectly. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: That should still work.  And if you do what I suggested in my answer above, _you will no longer have to select a mirror_ as you will already have done so in the `Rprofile.site` file.

Comment: Moreover you should [read up on https and why you should use it](http://blog.rstudio.org/2015/08/17/secure-https-connections-for-r/). You may need to set the `download.file.method`.

Comment: For me, specifying `method="wget"` works; but `method="libcurl"` (the default) doesn't, even though curl should support https.

Comment: See `capabilities()[["libcurl"]]` which is likely false meaning an insufficient curl library was found when R was built. The issue is local to your machine or distro or versions -- whichever is responsible for the binary.

Answer (score 5):

Please show what

```
Rscript -e 'print(options("repos"))'
```

contains.  For what it is worth, I set CRAN as well as two more [drat](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html) this way and never have an issue:

```
## Example of Rprofile.site snippet
local({
    r <- getOption("repos")
    r["CRAN"] <- "http://cran.rstudio.com"
    r["eddelbuettel"] <- "http://eddelbuettel.github.io/drat"
    r["ghrr"] <- "http://ghrr.github.io/drat"
    options(repos = r)
})
```

You can set CRAN, BioC and any other number of repositories this way.

Answer (score 0):

Since this pops up high in Google, I wanted to share that your R version could be the issue.