# Failing to install packages in R Studio

Tags: r

Whenever I try to install any package in R Studio, it returns following error:

```
> install.packages('xtable')
Error in install.packages : Line starting '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLI ...' is malformed!
```

Above, I am trying to install xtable, and for the life it, it keeps returning the same error. I have seen some solutions here about changing the mirror (which I did in Preferences->Packages and restarted) it didn't help either. Following is what is see in R_HOME/etc/repositories

```
menu_name       URL     default source  win.binary      mac.binary
CRAN    CRAN    @CRAN@  TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
BioCsoft        "BioC software" %bm/packages/%v/bioc    FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
BioCann "BioC annotation"       %bm/packages/%v/data/annotation FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
BioCexp "BioC experiment"       %bm/packages/%v/data/experiment FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
BioCextra       "BioC extra"    %bm/packages/%v/extra   FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
CRANextra       CRAN (extras)   "http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin"    FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
Omegahat        Omegahat        http://www.omegahat.org/R       FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    FALSE
R-Forge R-Forge http://R-Forge.R-project.org    FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
rforge.net      rforge.net      http://www.rforge.net   FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
```

Not sure if anything is messed up here. Being a noob, don't want to mess with it too much.

My system is running MacOS Catalina.

Comment: I don't know, but is there a firewall and/or proxy server in your network?

Comment: Hard to say. Can you try to install it with the option `verbose=TRUE, dependencies = TRUE` and post the ouput? Then you will get some more information on the progress of the installation.

Comment: Also, is it the first time you try to install packages on that system or has it worked before. What R version are you running?

Comment: "...it keeps returning the same error." _Don't you just wish computers could be less computer-like!_ Did you check this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32131430/cran-bioconductor-package-installs-fail-error-line-starting-doctype-html-p

Comment: @r2evans the only thing I did was to upgrade to MacOS 10.15 (Catalina), which I know has additional security. So far I am unable to figure out what changed.

Comment: @Edward, I checked that link, the solution there is basically to change the mirror. As I mentioned in my question, I tried changing the mirror but it didn't work for me.

Comment: @MKR, I tried with verbose option, it still returns the same error without any explanation:; install.packages('xtable', verbose=TRUE, dependencies=TRUE) 
Error in install.packages : Line starting '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLI ...' is malformed!
>

Comment: @MKR, R Studio version is 1.2.5033. It used to work fine on the same machine, different OS though (Mojave I think).

Comment: Catalina brought many security features, among them is much stricter control over several things. Beyond that vague hand-waving statement, I know very little about it, but I think the increased security is something to seriously look at. (Some of the changes are highlighted [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/443611/how-macos-catalinas-new-security-features-work/), though network firewalling is not explicitly listed.)

Comment: Perhaps you can try explicitly adding R (and Rterm and Rscript) to the [firewall rules](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/a-firewall-prevent-unwanted-connections-mac-mh34041/mac).

Comment: I tried turning off the firewall for good...didn't help :/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by modifying global parameters. Looks like in R Studio, you can either change default mirrors from two places:
1. Preference -> Packages 
2. Tools -> Global Options -> Packages

When I changed the download mirror using second option, it worked without issues.