# R package install fails with - Line starting '<html> ...' is malformed

Tags: r, installation, install.packages

I have recently tried to install packages for Microsoft R Open on multiple machines. I have always got the following error message:

```
> install.packages("dplyr")
Installing package into ‘/home/paljenczy/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/2016-01-01/src/contrib:
  Line starting '<html> ...' is malformed!
```

I have only experienced this error today, I think a week ago everything worked fine on all of my machines. One of them is a server so it does not have to do with my local settings. Do you have a clue why this happens? I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836371/r-bioconductor-installation-error-line-starting-doctype-html-publi-is) question - do you think it is a problem of some recent build?

Comment: From the google group of Microsoft R (Jianyang Zhao):I have same issue. It looks they updated mran address recently and install.packages() can't handle a redirect. You can install from cran by before they fix this problem

r = getOption("repos")
r["CRAN"] <- "http://cran.r-project.org" 
options(repos=r)
install.packages("gmp")

Comment: pajlenczy, please post that comment as an answer

Comment: Also, this issue is generic, nothing specifically about MRO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a comment as an answer:

From the google group of Microsoft R (Jianyang Zhao):I have same issue. It looks they updated mran address recently and install.packages() can't handle a redirect. You can install from cran by before they fix this problem r = getOption("repos") r["CRAN"] <- "cran.r-project.org"; options(repos=r) install.packages("gmp")

The issue is not specific to MRO.